# How do I properly use strtotime in an IF statement?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check for a specific time condition, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. Only the FIRST condition gets applied. It seems to me the second condition should be applied as it is past 9:59am central time.

I have:

```
<?php
$timezone       = date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$TheDate        = strtotime("April 1, 2016, 12:00 am");


if ($TheDate >= strtotime("March 30, 2016, 12:00 am") && $TheDate <= strtotime("April 1, 2016, 9:59 am")) {
    global $eventMsg;
    echo 'My name';
}

else if ($TheDate >= strtotime("April 1, 2016, 4:12 pm") && $TheDate <= strtotime("April 1, 2016, 4:59 pm")) {
    global $eventMsg;
    echo 'His name';
}

else {
    global $eventMsg;
    echo 'Pete\'s name';
}?>
```

I tested this two days ago and it was working while we were in the month of March, now I'm being fooled. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Also, syntax error in the last two lines.

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: Look at the output of this https://3v4l.org/ZYjjj 0:00 < 9:59, hence the first If get's applied

Comment: The output of the provided code is `My name`. What else do you expect?

Comment: paullb, first IF condition is echoed, I'm looking to have the second condition, 'His name' echoed.

Comment: But the first If block gets always applied due to `$TheDate        = strtotime("April 1, 2016, 12:00 am");`. You probably want to use `$TheDate = time();` instead if you want the current time.

Comment: @Marlon It won't do the second condition since you've set `$TheDate` to `strtotime("April 1, 2016, 12:00 am")`. It's only doing what you're telling it to.

Comment: If I want the current time? Including the date? According to your previous link, somehow the date isnt getting interpreted as an american style.

Comment: It does. I am just outputting the date in german 24h style. :-)

Comment: `time()` returns the current UNIX timestamp. What you also get with `strtotime()` (the UNIX timestamp of the passed date/time string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the code and figured out what I was trying to do, also with the help of Charlotte and the PHP Manual.

I simply added the time() function and formatted the time/date parameter.